# Can I fail the entire year of M1 if I fail a class in france?

Tags: masters, france

I am having a very bad experience in my first year of an MSc in France and have problems with a particular professor, so I might fail his class. Will failing his class make me fail the entire year? Can I apply again for another master's program if I fail this one?

Comment: I think this depends on your institution rules, but masters' degrees are usually not like that "all or nothing". I expect that they give you an opportunity to recover from a failed class.

Comment: Also, for each diploma in France (e.g. each mater's degree) there are written rules ("modalités de contrôle des connaissances", MCC) describing how you can validate or compensate credits. These rules often partly refer to guidelines defined at the university level.